# auth middleware with parameter - Laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware

if I add admin's guard

what's the difference between auth and guest middleware when I pass this parameter

1. auth:web
2. auth:admin
3. guest:web
4. guest:admin

Answer (score 0):

`auth` and `guest` are middleware, you are only passing parameters after the `:` part. The parameter is the guard(s) you want it to use. Without passing a parameter it uses the default guard.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Authentication - Protecting Routes - Specifying a Guard](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#protecting-routes)

Comment: ok , so what's the real difference between guest:web and guest:admin

Comment: it is the same middleware, you are just passing a parameter to tell it what "guard" to use, as the docs state ... "When attaching the `auth` middleware to a route, you may also specify which guard should be used to authenticate the user."  same thing for the `guest` middleware, you are telling it which guard to use to see if the user is a guest